# How to achive this design XAMARIN XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How to achieve this design in xamarin?
I am trying to implement a list, with the all row of 0th column fixed during horizontally scroll and all row of 1st column will scroll horizontally. Please see image.

I have list data. Do you know any plugin/component to achieve this ?

[image]

Here I am trying..

```
 <StackLayout Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4">
                          
    <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10" Spacing="50" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="List Header" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Label Text="18:00" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
        <Label Text="18:30" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
        <Label Text="19:00" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypes}" ItemTapped="DataType_Selected" >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               
                <ViewCell>
                   
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid >

                                <Label Text="{Binding DataName}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" TextColor="#f35e20" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Text="Avail" Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Text="Not" Grid.Column="4" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Text="Avail" Grid.Column="5" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />

                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: This would be very complex to build from scratch.  I’d suggest you look into one of the third party datagrid controls

Comment: I'm looking the third party datagrid controls. Thank you @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the grid or the stacklayout as the parent layout and then use the scrollview contains the stacklayout which has a listview in it.

[image]

Just like the picture shows, you can just use the scrollvoew to make the listview scroll both Vertically and Horizontally.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

  <StackLayout>
       
       //the listview
  </StackLayout>

</ScrollView>
```